# js console log string formating starting point

Tags: logging, console, formatting

```
let amounts = [1,10,100]
let animals = [cat,dog,horse]
for (let n = 0; n<3; n++){
console.log("I have " + amounts[n] + " of " + animals[n] + " in total" )
}
```

Currently I get:

```
I have 1 cat in total
I have 10 dog in total
I have 100 horse in total
```

Is there a way to format this log with "columns" (they are incoming one by one, and I cannot log them as table)

```
I have 1    cat    in total
I have 10   dog    in total
I have 100  horse  in total
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let amounts = [1, 10, 100]
let animals = ['cat', 'dog', 'horse']
for (let n = 0; n < 3; n++){
console.log("I have\t" + amounts[n] + "\t" + animals[n] + "\tin total" )
}
```

Another solution is to use `Array.forEach()`

```js
let amounts = [1, 10, 100]
let animals = ['cat', 'dog', 'horse']

amounts.forEach((amount, index) => {console.log(`I have\t${amount}\t${animals[index]}\tin total`)})
```